# Display radio inputs on separate lines but keep text on same line as radio selector

Tags: html, css, forms

I am trying to create a simple multiple-choice quiz. This is the layout I am trying to achieve:

[image]

However, I am having some difficulty implementing the CSS needed to control the spacing needed for that.

I changing the display for each input to "block" and while this put each radio button a separate line, it also put the text for that radio button on a separate line as well, so that it looked like this:

[image]

As that is clearly not what is wanted, how can I force each of the radio buttons to be on *separate* lines but also keep the text for each radio input on the *same* line? I also want to be able to reduce the space between the question number and the options for that question, and then increase the space between each question (each question is currently a div) and sometimes messing around with one thing screws up the other.

The full HTML and CSS for the page can be found here:
 http://interlinked.x10host.com/projects/landlines/telcoquiz.html

The relevant HTML is:

```
      <div id="quiz">
            <div id="quiztext">
                <p>Let's get started!</p>
                <p>You will be taking the 10-question Telephone Quiz. All questions are multiple-choice, with one correct answer each. If you pass, you will recieve the Honorary Telephone Award!</p>
            </div>
            <div id="form">
                <form id="telcoform">
                    <div class="quizItem"><p class="qNumber">1</p>
                        <input type="radio" name="question1" value="1a">Option A</input>
                        <input type="radio" name="question1" value="1b">Option B</input>
                    </div>
                    <div class="quizItem"><p class="qNumber">2</p>
                        <input type="radio" name="question2" value="2a">Option A</input>
                        <input type="radio" name="question2" value="2b">Option B</input>
                        <input type="radio" name="question2" value="2c">Option C</input>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The relevant CSS is:

```
    #quiz {
        display: none;
    }
    #beginButton, #quiztext {
        text-align: center;
    }
    #form {
        text-align: left;
        margin-left: 115px;
        margin-right: 115px;
    }
    #telcoform {

    }
    .quizItem {

    }
    .quizItem input {

    }
    .qNumber {
        font-family: 'merriweatherregular';
        font-weight: 700;
    }
```

Comment: put the input and text in a block element. you should be using `label` for the text, too. but regardless you need to include your code here on StackOverflow. Just enough to reproduce the issue. Probably all you need to do is include the code to replicate what's in your screenshot. See how to create a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have each input/text combo be on it's own line, just wrap them in a block element. Though your text should also be in a `label` that is associated with the `input` - isn't necessary, but is better, more accessible markup, and better UX because it allows you to click on the text to select the input.

```css
#beginButton,
#quiztext {
  text-align: center;
}

#form {
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 115px;
  margin-right: 115px;
}

#telcoform {}

.quizItem {}

.quizItem input {}

.qNumber {
  font-family: 'merriweatherregular';
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<div id="quiz">
  <div id="quiztext">
    <p>Let's get started!</p>
    <p>You will be taking the 10-question Telephone Quiz. All questions are multiple-choice, with one correct answer each. If you pass, you will recieve the Honorary Telephone Award!</p>
  </div>
  <div id="form">
    <form id="telcoform">
      <div class="quizItem">
        <p class="qNumber">1</p>
        <div><input type="radio" name="question1" value="1a" id="q-1a"><label for="q-1a">Option A</label></div>
        <div><input type="radio" name="question1" value="1b" id="q-1b"><label for="q-1b">Option B</label></div>
      </div>
      <div class="quizItem">
        <p class="qNumber">2</p>
        <div><input type="radio" name="question2" value="2a" id="q-2a"><label for="q-2a">Option A</label></div>
        <div><input type="radio" name="question2" value="2b" id="q-2b"><label for="q-2b">Option B</label></div>
          <div><input type="radio" name="question2" value="2c" id="q-2c"><label for="q-2c">Option C</label></div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: May I ask why an id for each input is necessary? Or is that just best practice?

Comment: @InterLinked that's how the `for` attribute on the `label` works. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label